# Typedef in template class not working

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

That might be a silly question, but I'm staring at this code for a while and can't think of what's wrong. On compiling:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

template <typename T>
struct my_string_map {
    typedef std::map<std::string, T> type;
};
template <typename T> bool add_to_string_map(my_string_map<T>::type map,
        std::string str, T x) {
    if (map.find(str) != map.end()) 
        return false;
    map[str] = x;
    return true;
}
```

I get:

```
foo.cpp:8: error: template declaration of ‘bool add_to_string_map’
foo.cpp:8: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘map’
foo.cpp:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘str’
foo.cpp:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘x’
```

(Definition of my_string_map class was taken from another thread of this forum)

When i specialize what template type I'm using, like in

```
bool add_to_string_int_map(my_string_map<int>::type map,
        std::string str, int x) {
    if (map.find(str) != map.end()) 
        return false;
    map[str] = x;
    return true;
}
```

everything works fine. Why it's not working and/or how to get it working?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Define "not working".  Presumably you get a compiler error message.  What is it?

Answer (score 7):

Try putting `typename` before the `my_string_map<T>::type` argument.

For more info, see: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-types.

Comment: Whoa, thanks. It works. The more i use templates, the more weird they seem...

Answer (score 4):

`my_string_map<T>::type` is a *dependent name*, as it depends on the template parameter `T`. For dependent names, you need to use `typename`:

```
template <typename T>
bool add_to_string_map(typename my_string_map<T>::type map, std::string str, T x) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will not be able to deduce T. It seems obvious to a human but from the point of view of the compiler, this kind of deduction is impossible. The specialization works because you're no longer asking the compiler to deduce T.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be able to?  There's a parameter (the third) of type `T`.

Comment: @Ben: Last time I checked, it won't do that.